# Instagram API returns empty array

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Calling these endpoints

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows`
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by`

with perfectly valid access-token, and access scope of `follower_list relationships`

returns `200 OK`, and data as empty array []

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Sandbox mode, it will only return users that are in your approved sandbox user list.

Add one of the user you follow to the sandbox and it will show up in the API response.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it - however to me this limitation doesn't make much sense, I've added access token owner to sandbox, and querying info about access token owner, so I expect all info to come back. I dont expect to add every related user to sandbox for them to appear in relationships..

Comment: @dark_ruby From the looks of it, they are trying to prevent users from taking advantage of it to build analytics for their own accounts (it is considered an 'invalid use case' in their docs). In short, I don't think their API targets general consumers anymore.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work now.Added a user in sandbox and it's just stuck on pending for last two days.Does the person added need to confirm or something.Would really like to get this working.Any feedback/updates on the API usage would be much appreciate!

Comment: @mikeym The other person need to approve it in the developer instagram website. No email or other notification is being sent.

Comment: wait so i am registered my app I cannot see my followers?? omg instagram is bunch of ...$#!